# Jumping to the implementation instead of the generated interface in Xcode with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, rx-swift

When jumping to a definition with `ctrl-cmd-j` in Xcode, I often get sent to a generated interface for the method instead of the actual implementation.  How can I jump to the actual implementation instead?  I end up having to manually find the file/implementation manually, which is very cumbersome.

For example, while browsing [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), if I `ctrl-cmd-j` while over a `subscribeNext` call, I get sent to a generated interface file which just has the method signature: `public func subscribeNext(onNext: (Self.E) -> Void) -> Disposable`.  However, I know the real implementation lives at `RxSwift/Observable+Extensions.swift` and I end up having to manually navigate to that file.

How can I get off this crazy train?

Comment: Is CTRL-J a custom shortcut of yours? I use CTRL-CMD-J to jump to definitions, and it works well.

Comment: Ah yea my bad, that's what I had meant.  I've edited my post.